# delete with id api call from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-delete

when i call delete method in angularjs as below, then it doesn't work.

```
$http.post('/api/Student/delete/'+$scope.delrollno)
                .then(function (response) {   .....
```

in controller I have method as below.

```
public void Delete(int id)
    { .............
    }
```

in console it gives error, 405 (Method Not Allowed), why it is not going into controller delete method?

Answer (score 2):

It means that your api is expecting another *http method* different than **POST** for that action. Did you try with **DELETE** instead, like this:

```
$http.delete('/api/Student/delete/'+$scope.delrollno)
```

?

Comment: actually its now working.... with $http.delete. yesterday it was not working... may be values stored in cache was a problem. .. .anyways thankx..

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I've solved that before by cleaning the web browser cache. For future reference, could you mark the answer as correct? Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree @Asiel is right, Post is probably not allowed, use http.delete or maybe you forget to add config or data to your call.

[enter link description here](https://httpstatusdogs.com/405-method-not-allowed)